# C# merge two properties into a list and filter unique values

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, data-structures

To explain my problem I have created this simplified example with a `BookBundle`, which contains two `Book`s:

```
public class BookBundle
{
    public Book Book1 { get; }
    public Book Book2 { get; }
}
```

But now I have a lot of `BookBundle`s, but I don't know which unique `Book`s I have in my library. For this I created a function:

```
public static Book[] GetUniqueBooks(BookBundle[] bundles)
{
    // Return all unique books
}
```

What is the most efficient way to implement this function? Is there maybe some Linq function I could use, or should I use a `List` or `Dictionary` to keep track of which unique items I've found while looping through them? And which would be the fastest (lowest algorithmic complexity)?

Comment: How do you know you have a unique bundle?  What if one book in a bundle is unique and the other isn't?  Please explain more about what this is all about...

Comment: You could store your uniqhe books in a Dictionary with key set to the ISBN code of the book and the value to the Book object

Comment: @rory.ap A bundle is always unique, in the sense that it never contains the same two books as another bundle. But a book can be in multiple bundles.

Comment: How much books do you have? What is their equality?

Comment: @eocron This must work with any amount of books, let's say there are a thousand. For comparison either an `ID`/`ISBN` property or `==` can be used.

Comment: The answers below assumes that you have the same instance of book stored many times. Is this true?

Comment: @Steve Yes one book can be in multiple bundles, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Not exactly. I mean, how do you instantiate the same book present in two bundles? If you use the same instance then the solutions that uses SelectMany and Distinct should work very well. But if the same book is added through a new instance for each book (IE new Book("Title1") for the first bundle and then again new Book("Title1") for a second bundle) then you need a different approach (or a different comparer)

Comment: @Steve Oh I see. There is only one instance per book in this case, but the  books can also be compared with an overloaded `==` as I mentioned previously, which I believe `Distinct` uses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` from `System.Linq`.

```
bundles.SelectMany(b => new Book[] {b.Book1, b.Book2}).Distinct();
```

Comment: I don't understand how this will work.  For each bundle, we would get an array of two books.  Correct?  So 5 bundles would result in 1 array of 5 arrays, each of two books... but we want a flat array of 10 books.  (assuming distinct, etc)

Comment: No, that's not how `SelectMany` works. Read the doc, it takes an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable<T>`'s and flattens the combined contents of all of them into one `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple implementation to solve your problem and with the advantage to work also if you create two different instances of the same book.

```
public Book[] GetUniqueBooks(BookBundle[] bundles)
{
    Dictionary<string, Book> dict = new Dictionary<string, Book>();
    foreach (BookBundle b in bundles)
    {
        Book bk;
        if(!dict.TryGetValue(b.Book1.ISBN, out bk))
            dict.Add(b.Book1.ISBN, b.Book1);
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(b.Book2.ISBN, out bk))
            dict.Add(b.Book2.ISBN, b.Book2);

    }
    return dict.Values.ToArray();
}
```

Of course this assumes that you have defined in your class a property that uniquely identifies the book. In this case I have used the International Standard Book Number as key in the dictionary